# Popup window on a ListView Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, popupwindow

I have created a custom arrayadapter for my listview. It has a player name and the score, I also have a add button on the cell, when that button is clicked I want a popup screen to appear, Here is where the user can add the score of the player. This popup window has 6 buttons "+1", "+2" "+10" ..etc and a done button. When the done button is clicked the score gets updated.

I am handling the add button click event on my customArraryAdapter class, so I have to create the popup here as well. I have searched and tried to do this with no success.

**What I tried so far:**
I have a `View = convertView` and a `viewHolder = holder` The problem is I'm not so sure what to pass as the parameter to create a popup. The code below is myCustomArrayAdapter class. I have also read popups cant handle touch events, but some are saying it can. Since my popup has a lot of buttons maybe this might be a great solution.

**This is in  @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  Method in CustomArrayAdapter Class**

```
//Handle add button click
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        addScores(convertView);

        //list gets updated
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

});
```

**My addScores method looks like this**
[image]

```
  private void addScores(View v){
        PopupWindow pw;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)v.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weight_popup, (ViewGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.linlay_weight_popup));
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        pw.showAsDropDown(btnSelectWeight);

    }
```

Comment: You can pass the context from adapter . From there you can create LayoutInflator object using  LayoutInflator.from(context) method.

Comment: Can you provide a solution with code? I have tried passing Context right now but im still getting red text on getSystemService, and is it true about not able to handle touch/click event on popup window ?

Comment: Check this link https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/

Comment: When I try to pass convertview I get this message, is there anyway around this without using final? "convertview is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: Assign convertView to a final variable then use that final variable as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass  View that will be displayed in popup the same way you do.

Consider this:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weight_popup, (ViewGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.linlay_weight_popup));
```

Your weight_popup layout should contain 6 buttons, which would have onClick there you update scores.
Something like:

```
Button btn1 = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //update your score here.
                }
            });

//other buttons..

pw = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
```